# Verify OTP in expressj with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating web services and trying to verify otp but getting user blank after console log , Where i am wrong here is my code.Thanks in advance.

```
app.post('/verify', function(req, res, next) {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cuts');
  var db = mongoose.connection;
  var PwdSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    phone: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    otp: {
      type: String,
      required: true,

    }

  });

  User = mongoose.model('usersotp', PwdSchema);
  User.findOne({
    phone: req.body.phone
  }, function(err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {

      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
      } else {
        console.log("no data found");
      }
    }

  });
  res.send("Any text");
});
```

Comment: Make mongoose debug mode to true. `mongoose.set('debug', true)`; code looks correct

Comment: Can you console the value of req.body.phone ?? It should be number as your models has phone with number type.

Comment: @Jack , req.body.phone is not empty , i checked this

Comment: @PreetiDhariwal Is that value in the string type? check using `typeof req.body.phone`

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @PreetiDhariwal Is it working? Chal raha hai kya?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, here's is where you are goofing up:

Your model requires the **number** type for phone and you are sending the **string** and that is why it is not matching.

```
const inputPhone = typeof req.body.phone === "string" ? parseInt(req.body.phone) : req.body.phone;
User.findOne({ phone: inputPhone }, function (err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        if (user) {
            console.log(user);
        }
        else {
            console.log("no data found");
        }
    }
});
```

***Let me know if this does not work.***